transitioning underline for sub menu items stretch across its container width, not the width of item name
I'm not sure where I've gone wrong but I did have my submenu items with a line after/underneath them which would transition to be the width of the word see here: working
Ive made some changes to class names in various parts of my html and css in preparation to build out the mobile version, along with some other formatting changes and somewhere along the line ive broken this. Now the transitioning line expands to fill 100% of the width of its container. see here: broken
I really dont know what ive done wrong here, Ive double checked the code, but i just cant see how I broke it. Hopefully someone can spot where ive gone wrong. fingers crossed.
I have 2 navs in my site (mobile and Desktop) both are broken, so for the sake of keeping the code down Ive included the html and Css for just the desktop version
html
<body>
    <!-- Header Section Start -->
    
    
<section class="header">
    <div class="container" data-type="headercontainer">
        <nav class="nav-desktop">
            <div class="nav-menu-links" id="navmenulinks">
                <ul class="ul-upper-menu">
                    <li class="li-main-menu-item"><a class="a-main-menu-item" href="index.html">A World at War</a></li>
                    <li class="li-main-menu-item"><a class="a-main-menu-item" href="#">The Road to War</a></li>
                    <li class="li-main-menu-item"><a class="a-main-menu-item" href="#">Desktop Site</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="ul-lower-menu">
                    <li class="li-main-menu-item-with-submenu">
                        <a class="a-main-menu-item-with-submenu" href="#">Eastern Europe</a>
                        <div class="sub-menu-1">
                            <ul class="ul-sub-menu-1">
                                <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Invasion of Poland</a></li>
                                <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Winter War</a></li>
                                <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Barbarossa</a></li>
                                <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Typhoon</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="li-main-menu-item-with-submenu">
                        <a class="a-main-menu-item-with-submenu" href="#">Western Europe</a>
                        <div class="sub-menu-1">
                            <ul class="ul-sub-menu-1">
                                <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Phoney War</a></li>
                                <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Operation Weserbung</a></li>
                                <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Low Countries</a></li>
                                <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Battle of France</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="li-main-menu-item-with-submenu">
                        <a class="a-main-menu-item-with-submenu" href="#">Italy and the Balkans</a>
                        <div class="sub-menu-1">
                            <ul class="ul-sub-menu-1">
                                <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Greece Attacked</a></li>
                                <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Invasion of Yugoslavia</a></li>
                                <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Greece and Crete</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="li-main-menu-item-with-submenu">
                        <a class="a-main-menu-item-with-submenu" href="#">North Africa</a>
                        <div class="sub-menu-1">
                            <ul class="ul-sub-menu-1">
                                <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Italy Advances</a></li>
                                <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">British Reposte</a></li>
                                <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Enter Rommel</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="li-main-menu-item-with-submenu">
                        <a class="a-main-menu-item-with-submenu" href="#">Battle of the Atlantic</a>
                        <div class="sub-menu-1">
                            <ul class="ul-sub-menu-1">
                                <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Hunt the Bismarck</a></li>
                                <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">1st Happy Time</a></li>
                                <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">2nd Happy Time</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="li-main-menu-item-with-submenu">
                        <a class="a-main-menu-item-with-submenu" href="#">War for the Pacific</a>
                        <div class="sub-menu-1">
                            <ul class="ul-sub-menu-1">
                                <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Pearl Harbour</a></li>
                                <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Onward Rush</a></li>
                                <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Singapore</a></li>
                                <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Great Marianas Turkey Shoot</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="images/logo/world-war-2-logo.webp" alt="World-War-2.org Logo" title="World-War-2.org"> </a>
        </nav>
</section>



</body>

CSS
root {
    --clr-primary-400: #f44336;
    --clr-accent-100: #ffffff;
    --clr-accent-900: #000000;
    --font-family-primary: "helvetica";
    --font-family-secondary: "Amatic SC", sans-serif;
}




/* Remove Some Defaults */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    /*font: inherit;*/
    font-family: "helvetica";
}

/* Set Core Root Defaults */
html:focus-within {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

/* Set Core Body Defaults */
body {
    text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
    
}

/* Make Images Easier to Work With */
img,
picture,
svg {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}


/* Header Desktop Nav Section */

.container[data-type="headercontainer"] {
    height: 100vh;
    max-width: 1140px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.25),#999393),url(images/hero-photo/a-world-at-war-cover-d-1040-l85.webp);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    margin: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
    container-type: inline-size;
    
}

.nav-desktop {
    display: flex;
    padding: 1% 1%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}
    /* Logo */
    nav .logo {
        width: 175px;
        
    }


.nav-menu-links {
    flex: 1;
    /*text-align: right;*/
}

nav .ul-upper-menu {
    /*max-width:contain;*/
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: nowrap; /*WRAPS MENU LINKS*/
    margin: 0px 0px 0px -3px;
}
nav .ul-lower-menu {
    /*max-width:contain;*/
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: nowrap; /*WRAPS MENU LINKS*/
    margin:0px 0px 0px -3px;
    
}


    nav ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px 6px 5px 6px;
        margin: 0px 2px 0px 2px;
        position: relative;
        list-style: none;
    }

.li-main-menu-item, .li-main-menu-item-with-submenu {
    /*background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
    border-radius: 5px 5px;*/
    
}

nav a {
    /*height: 90%;*/
    display: flex;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Amatic SC", sans-serif;
    /*text-align:justify;*/
    /*padding: 0 30px;*/
    list-style: none;
}

nav .a-main-menu-item {
    /*height: 90%;*/
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    list-style: none;
}

.a-main-menu-item-with-submenu {
    /*height: 80%;*/
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    list-style: none;
}


/* Main Menu Item Hover Effects Start */
nav ul .li-main-menu-item::after {
    content: '';
    width: 0%;
    height: 2px;
    background: rgb(0, 191, 255);
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

nav ul .li-main-menu-item:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
}

nav ul .a-main-menu-item:hover {
    color: rgba(0, 191, 255);
}


/* Main Menu Item Hover Effects End */

/* Main Menu Item With Submenu Hover Effects Start */
nav ul .li-main-menu-item-with-submenu::after {
    content: '';
    width: 0%;
    height: 2px;
    background: rgb(0, 191, 255);
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

nav ul .li-main-menu-item-with-submenu:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
}



/* Main Menu Item With Submenu Hover Effects End */


/* Hide Sub-Menu-1 being displayed until Hovered on */
.sub-menu-1 {
    display: none;
}


/* SUB MENU 1 CONFIG */


.sub-menu-1 {
    /*transition: transform ease-in-out 3s;*/
}

.ul-sub-menu-1 {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(0, 191, 255, 0.5);
    left: 0;
    top: 37px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px;
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 0px;
    width: max-content;
    /*transition: transform ease-in-out 1s;*/
}

.li-sub-menu-1-item {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;

}

.a-sub-menu-1-item {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    list-style: none;
    
}

/* Sub Menu 1 Hover Effects Start */
nav ul .li-main-menu-item-with-submenu:hover .sub-menu-1 {
    content: '';
    width: 0%;
    /*height: 0px;*/
    /*  background: #ffffff;*/
    display: flex;
    transition: all 1.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease;
}

/* Creates a Dynamic Line after each Sub-Menu-1-item */
.li-sub-menu-1-item::after {
    content: '';
    width: 0%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.li-sub-menu-1-item:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
}
/*nav ul .li-main-menu-item-with-submenu:hover .sub-menu-1 {
    transition: all 1.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease;
}*/

/* Changes the Parent Menu Name Color when Sub-menu-1-item is hovered on */
.li-sub-menu-1-item.active.parent > a, .li-main-menu-item-with-submenu:hover > a {
    color: rgb(0, 191, 255);
}
/* Sub Menu 1 Hover Effects End */


The <li> with the class .li-main-menu-item-with-submenu that has the pseudo element of the underline, is displayed as if block so its width is 100%.
Luckily, the class .li-main-menu-item-with-submenu doesn't need to be on the <li> but can be on an inner element that will be display: inline-block. So the order is li > span.li-sub-menu-1-item > a.
I didn't change your entire markup, but you can see a working example under menu item Eastern Europe > Winter War


root {
  --clr-primary-400: #f44336;
  --clr-accent-100: #ffffff;
  --clr-accent-900: #000000;
  --font-family-primary: "helvetica";
  --font-family-secondary: "Amatic SC", sans-serif;
}


/* Remove Some Defaults */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  /*font: inherit;*/
  font-family: "helvetica";
}


/* Set Core Root Defaults */

html:focus-within {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}


/* Set Core Body Defaults */

body {
  text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
}


/* Make Images Easier to Work With */

img,
picture,
svg {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}


/* Header Desktop Nav Section */

.container[data-type="headercontainer"] {
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 1140px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), #999393), url(images/hero-photo/a-world-at-war-cover-d-1040-l85.webp);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
  container-type: inline-size;
}

.nav-desktop {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1% 1%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}


/* Logo */

nav .logo {
  width: 175px;
}

.nav-menu-links {
  flex: 1;
  /*text-align: right;*/
}

nav .ul-upper-menu {
  /*max-width:contain;*/
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  /*WRAPS MENU LINKS*/
  margin: 0px 0px 0px -3px;
}

nav .ul-lower-menu {
  /*max-width:contain;*/
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  /*WRAPS MENU LINKS*/
  margin: 0px 0px 0px -3px;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 6px 5px 6px;
  margin: 0px 2px 0px 2px;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

.li-main-menu-item,
.li-main-menu-item-with-submenu {
  /*background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
    border-radius: 5px 5px;*/
}

nav a {
  /*height: 90%;*/
  display: flex;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Amatic SC", sans-serif;
  /*text-align:justify;*/
  /*padding: 0 30px;*/
  list-style: none;
}

nav .a-main-menu-item {
  /*height: 90%;*/
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  list-style: none;
}

.a-main-menu-item-with-submenu {
  /*height: 80%;*/
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  list-style: none;
}


/* Main Menu Item Hover Effects Start */

nav ul .li-main-menu-item::after {
  content: '';
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: rgb(0, 191, 255);
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

nav ul .li-main-menu-item:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul .a-main-menu-item:hover {
  color: rgba(0, 191, 255);
}


/* Main Menu Item Hover Effects End */


/* Main Menu Item With Submenu Hover Effects Start */

nav ul .li-main-menu-item-with-submenu::after {
  content: '';
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: rgb(0, 191, 255);
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

nav ul .li-main-menu-item-with-submenu:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Main Menu Item With Submenu Hover Effects End */


/* Hide Sub-Menu-1 being displayed until Hovered on */

.sub-menu-1 {
  display: none;
}


/* SUB MENU 1 CONFIG */

.sub-menu-1 {
  /*transition: transform ease-in-out 3s;*/
}

.ul-sub-menu-1 {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(0, 191, 255, 0.5);
  left: 0;
  top: 37px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px;
  padding: 4px 0px 4px 0px;
  width: max-content;
  /*transition: transform ease-in-out 1s;*/
}

.li-sub-menu-1-item {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

.a-sub-menu-1-item {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  list-style: none;
}


/* Sub Menu 1 Hover Effects Start */

nav ul .li-main-menu-item-with-submenu:hover .sub-menu-1 {
  content: '';
  width: 0%;
  /*height: 0px;*/
  /*  background: #ffffff;*/
  display: flex;
  transition: all 1.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease;
}


/* Creates a Dynamic Line after each Sub-Menu-1-item */

.li-sub-menu-1-item::after {
  content: '';
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.li-sub-menu-1-item:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}


/*nav ul .li-main-menu-item-with-submenu:hover .sub-menu-1 {
    transition: all 1.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease;
}*/


/* Changes the Parent Menu Name Color when Sub-menu-1-item is hovered on */

.li-sub-menu-1-item.active.parent>a,
.li-main-menu-item-with-submenu:hover>a {
  color: rgb(0, 191, 255);
}


/* Sub Menu 1 Hover Effects End */


/* add this: */

.li-sub-menu-1-item {
  display: inline-block;
}
<body>
  <!-- Header Section Start -->


  <section class="header">
    <div class="container" data-type="headercontainer">
      <nav class="nav-desktop">
        <div class="nav-menu-links" id="navmenulinks">
          <ul class="ul-upper-menu">
            <li class="li-main-menu-item"><a class="a-main-menu-item" href="index.html">A World at War</a></li>
            <li class="li-main-menu-item"><a class="a-main-menu-item" href="#">The Road to War</a></li>
            <li class="li-main-menu-item"><a class="a-main-menu-item" href="#">Desktop Site</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="ul-lower-menu">
            <li class="li-main-menu-item-with-submenu">
              <a class="a-main-menu-item-with-submenu" href="#">Eastern Europe</a>
              <div class="sub-menu-1">
                <ul class="ul-sub-menu-1">
                  <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Invasion of Poland</a></li>
                  <li>
                    <span class="li-sub-menu-1-item">
                  <a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Winter War</a>
                  </span>

                  </li>
                  <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Barbarossa</a></li>
                  <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Typhoon</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="li-main-menu-item-with-submenu">
              <a class="a-main-menu-item-with-submenu" href="#">Western Europe</a>
              <div class="sub-menu-1">
                <ul class="ul-sub-menu-1">
                  <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Phoney War</a></li>
                  <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Operation Weserbung</a></li>
                  <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Low Countries</a></li>
                  <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Battle of France</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="li-main-menu-item-with-submenu">
              <a class="a-main-menu-item-with-submenu" href="#">Italy and the Balkans</a>
              <div class="sub-menu-1">
                <ul class="ul-sub-menu-1">
                  <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Greece Attacked</a></li>
                  <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Invasion of Yugoslavia</a></li>
                  <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Greece and Crete</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="li-main-menu-item-with-submenu">
              <a class="a-main-menu-item-with-submenu" href="#">North Africa</a>
              <div class="sub-menu-1">
                <ul class="ul-sub-menu-1">
                  <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Italy Advances</a></li>
                  <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">British Reposte</a></li>
                  <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Enter Rommel</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="li-main-menu-item-with-submenu">
              <a class="a-main-menu-item-with-submenu" href="#">Battle of the Atlantic</a>
              <div class="sub-menu-1">
                <ul class="ul-sub-menu-1">
                  <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Hunt the Bismarck</a></li>
                  <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">1st Happy Time</a></li>
                  <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">2nd Happy Time</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="li-main-menu-item-with-submenu">
              <a class="a-main-menu-item-with-submenu" href="#">War for the Pacific</a>
              <div class="sub-menu-1">
                <ul class="ul-sub-menu-1">
                  <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Pearl Harbour</a></li>
                  <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Onward Rush</a></li>
                  <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Singapore</a></li>
                  <li class="li-sub-menu-1-item"><a class="a-sub-menu-1-item" href="#">Great Marianas Turkey Shoot</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="images/logo/world-war-2-logo.webp" alt="World-War-2.org Logo" title="World-War-2.org"> </a>
      </nav>

      <!-- you are missing next div -->
    </div>
  </section>



</body>



